extended classes do not print after using it
I started with dart and Flutter a week a go and I am building an app.
I wanted to create my own constructors for Row and Column, that will answer my needs.
Here is code:
class CharBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String theChar;
  const CharBox( { required this.theChar, super.key } );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color:Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary ),
      ),
      child: Text(theChar),
    );
  }
}

class CharBoxRow extends Row{

  CharBoxRow( List<String> rowOfChars, {super.key} ){
    
    List<CharBox> listOfChildren = <CharBox>[];
    for( int i = 0 ; i<rowOfChars.length ; ++i ){
      listOfChildren.add( CharBox(theChar : rowOfChars[i]) );
    }
    // ignore: unused_label
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center;
    // ignore: unused_label
    children: listOfChildren;
  }

}

class CharStackColumn extends Column{

  CharStackColumn( List<String> alphabet, {super.key} ){
    List<CharBoxRow> lines = <CharBoxRow>[];
    for( int i = 0 ; i<alphabet.length ; ++i ){
      print( i );
      List<String> holder = <String>[];
      for( int z = alphabet.length-i ; z<alphabet.length ; ++z ){
        holder.add( alphabet[z] );
      }
      for( int j = i ; j<alphabet.length ; ++j ){
        holder.add( alphabet[j] );
      }
      lines.add( CharBoxRow( holder ) );
    }

    // ignore: unused_label
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center;
    // ignore: unused_label
    children:lines;
  }
}

Then I tried to call it like that:
CharStackColumn( alphabet )

Yet nothing is printed. What do I do wrong?
alphabet variable is list of all alphabet letters.

check https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#can-i-extend-and-customize-the-bundled-widgets

I'm not sure why nothing is printed unless alphabet happens to be empty at the time you construct CharStackColumn.  Additionally, you should use debugPrint instead of print in Flutter since print might drop output.

@pskink are You refering to that I should build separate widget for that?
But that was not realy my aim here.

yes, this is flutter's philosophy: prefer composition over inheritance, what you did in your answer is like a bit "fighting" with its philosophy

@pskink You are right ;) well knowledge is there. So I will take your advice for future.

So I have solved this issue.
The issue was:
Column and Row are widgets with only final variables. This means that, you can only asign them values during constructing. What's is suprising, inside constructor it is already too late.
So I updated old code to this:
class CharStackColumn extends Column {
  CharStackColumn(List<String> alphabet, {super.key})
      : super(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: _generateChildren(alphabet),
        );

  static List<Widget> _generateChildren(List<String> alphabet) {
    List<Widget> lines = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; ++i) {
      List<String> holder = [];
      for (int z = alphabet.length - i; z < alphabet.length; ++z) {
        holder.add(alphabet[z]);
      }
      for (int j = i; j < alphabet.length; ++j) {
        holder.add(alphabet[j]);
      }
      lines.add(CharBoxRow(rowOfChars: holder));
    }
    return lines;
  }
}

As You can see, fial variables can be initialised with :super(). So we do not construct the values for them in cosntructor but we do that in separate method.
